# Travis CI failed because installing dependencies timed out

Tags: github, deployment, continuous-integration, latex, travis-ci

Travis CI for my Github repo keeps failing and I didn't know why, until I read through the Job log and figured out that many dependencies couldn't be downloaded on their machines.

For example, the `xcolor` package failed to install:

```
[20/23, 03:54/04:02] install: xcolor [17k]
Downloading 
   ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final/archive/xcolor.tar.xz
did not succeed, please retry.
TLPDB::_install_package: couldn't unpack ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final/archive/xcolor.tar.xz to /home/travis/texmf
```

which results in the following error:

```
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'xcolor.sty' from line
  '! LaTeX Error: File `xcolor.sty' not found.'
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'pdflatex', no output was made
```

The problem is I'm working on a LaTeX project, and LaTeX environments tend to be huge with lots of supporting packages. Here is the relevant part of my `setup.sh`, which is already the minimal requirement:

```
sudo tlmgr install \
    xkeyval ifthen amsmath bm \
    longtable ctex tabu array \
    colortbl berasans graphicx longtable \
    etoolbox lastpage amssymb mathrsfs \
    multirow xeCJK environ after \
    booktabs hyperref epstopdf tabu \
    fancyhdr listings amsfonts latexsym \
    hhline CJK longtable pifont \
    geometry ifpdf bmpsize hologo \
    fancybox appendix amsbsy paralist \
    tabularx xCJK2uni hologo calc \
    fontenc ifxetex xcolor palatino
```

Can I make sure that all required packages are successfully downloaded & installed before the building phase, say, by letting the server to retry several times? If so, how?

Comment: The frequency of such failures has increased in recent months. I don't know of a way to avoid it, but whenever I've had such a failure, I restart the build and generally speaking, it succeeds the second time around. Do you use the Precise or the Trusty build environment? I'm still on Precise but I was wondering if things would be any better in Trusty.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Timeouts-installing-dependencies):

> If you are getting network timeouts when trying to download dependencies, either use the built in retry feature of your dependency manager or wrap your install commands in the `travis_retry` function.

For example, in your `.travis.yml`:

```
install: travis_retry pip install myawesomepackage
```

`travis_retry` will attempt up three times if the return code is non-zero.